# getting command not found error while executing a command using subprocess in cron

Tags: python, cron, subprocess

While executing a command through subprocess in the linux command line it is working but while executing through cron it is raising an error command not found. Why is this happening?

Code:

`import subprocess
cmd = 'command of a web tool which i created'
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
output, error = process.communicate()`

it is giving an error /bash/sh: command 'XXXX' not found

I also tried using 
Code:
`import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)`

it is giving an error: CalledProcessError: Command 'XXXX' returned non-zero exit status 127

Comment: Most probably it is not in your PATH. If it is shell script try to use absolute path in your command